# Jetty logging Config error

Tags: java, jetty

I want to set-up Jetty for logging as described here - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html

But launch process finishes with error:

```
[WARNING] Config error at <Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection"><Set name="handlers">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler"><Item>
          <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
        </Item><Item>
          <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
        </Item><Item>
          <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
        </Item></Array>
    </Set></New>
</Set>
[WARNING] Failed startup of context JettyWebAppContext@2fa8ecf4@2fa8ecf4/,file:/.../test/JettyMavenHelloWarApp/src/main/webapp/,file:/.../test/JettyMavenHelloWarApp/src/main/webapp/
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.setHandler(class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.configure(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection$1.run(HandlerCollection.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

My jetty-web.xml that is inside WEB-INF has next configuration:

```
<Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
        <Item>
          <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
<Ref refid="RequestLog">
  <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
      <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Arg>
      <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="extended">false</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Ref>
```

What I did wrong?

I compile and run my WAR file with next command:
`mvn jetty:run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its choking on that <Arg> tag.  In my jetty.xml I configure the access log like

```
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Set handler Collection Structure                            --> 
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
     <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
       ...
       <!-- Built-in Jetty AccessLog log -->
       <Item>
         <New id="AccessLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
       </Item>
       ...
     </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>

<!-- Built-in Jetty AccessLog log -->
<Ref id="AccessLog">
  <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
      <Set name="filename"><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/access.yyyy_mm_dd.log</Set>
      <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyyMMdd</Set>
      <Set name="retainDays">7</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="extended">false</Set>
      <Set name="logLatency">true</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Ref>
```

I set up the Handler to give it a name then I configure the handler through its <Ref>.  The filename gets set in a <Set> tag, just like all the other parameters.

Also note that it is the "id" attribute you are setting in <Ref id="AccessLog"> NOT "refid" like your example configuration show.

Comment: Can you, please, show me your pom.xml? I found out that org.mortbay.jetty should be changed probably to something new.

Comment: @Tom.  I don't have a pom.xml file.  We use gradle and the task that assembles the jetty configuration directory just copies files and a directory structure from the source repo to the build directory directly.

Comment: My Jetty version was old. I did update, but on your code get warning: `No object for refid=AccessLog`

Comment: Plus JAVA_HOME was not set up properly and do update to Java 7 (this is if somebody else will have issue).

Comment: I still get No object for refid=AccessLog. What else do you have in your config?

Comment: @Tom file a new question about your `No object for refid` question.

Comment: I put this not into jetty.xml, but jetty-web.xml and for this reason it failed.